# Why is も used twice in this sentence?

Tags: particle-も

I found this sentence, and I kinda understand the meaning and use of も, but I want to understand why it is used twice:

> 人間{にんげん}**も**ロボット**も**区別{くべつ}しない

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These types of "why" questions are difficult to answer, but I would say that it was because the repetition makes the phrase sound emphatic both quickly and effectively.

Interestingly enough, this is far from being a Japanese-only phenomenon.

In English, one says "neither A nor B". The "n" sound is repeated.

In French, it is "ni A ni B".  Double "n", again.

In Japanese, we just happen to use 「AもBも」.  Double "m" for us.