# Meaning of verb + つもりも + potential verb + 程

Tags: meaning, verbs, expressions, potential-form, grammar

In a letter by a mangaka at the end of a manga, I encountered the following sentence:

> 〝正しいこと〟なんて**描くつもりも描ける程**、自分を上等とも思っていないけど〝つまらないこと〟だけはしないようにしていきたいなって思います

Is verb + つもりも + potential verb + 程 a fixed expression or do I have to interpret it literally?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqd1D.jpg) you can see the original page. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28880/why-is-%e3%82%82-used-twice-in-this-sentence

Comment: Was it 「上等も」 or 「上等とも」?

Comment: It was 上等とも, I corrected it, thank you @l'électeur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be parsing it correctly, I'm afraid...

I think you could probably parse it as something like...

> ［〝正しいこと〟なんて描くつもり**も**］、［描ける程、自分を上等と**も**思ってい］**ない**けど...

And you could split it to:

→〝正しいこと〟なんて描くつもり**もない**
+ （〝正しいこと〟が）描ける程、自分を上等と**も**思ってい**ない**けど...

「XXもYYも～～ない」(or 「XXもないしYYも～～ない」) = "neither XX nor YY"