# XもVba YもV pattern

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, phrases, particle-も

A girl is on a date with a hot guy in a flashy sports car

> とにかくザックは注目を集める。
>
> **車も目立てば、本人も目立つ**。信号待ちで止まろうものなら道行く女性は皆振り返るし、中にはスマホのカメラを向ける人すらいる。

Why is も used twice here and not, for example, a は in the first part? Is this a fixed pattern which requires も both times? What nuance would be different if は were to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a fixed pattern that requires two も's. It's hard to explain "why", but Japanese も can be used twice to list two similar things (e.g., 国語も英語も得意です, [泣いても笑っても](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B3%A3%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E7%AC%91%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82)これで最後だ).

- [Meaning of 「X 一緒なら Y 一緒」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40420/5010)
- [What nuances do the も…ば…も structure carry?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52420/5010)
- [What is the grammar behind もなければ、なければ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73839/5010)
- JGram: [も～ば～も](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=mo-ba-mo)

> What nuance would be different if は were to be used?

Simply, 車は目立てば本人も目立つ would make no sense to me.

Comment: 一応、「車は目立つわ本人は目立つ（わ）」という言い方はありますね…