# Understanding「お金持ってて悪い人じゃなければ」

Tags: manga

A college student リナ shares her experience with パパ活 (each line represents a single bubble in manga)

> あのね
>
> リナ、パパ活やってるの
>
> ...普通の食事だけじゃないやつ...
>
> お金持ってて悪い人じゃなければ
>
> お父さんぐらいの歳のおじさんとも
>
> 平気で寝られる

I have trouble comprehending lines 3 to 5. Does it mean "with guys who want more than just a meal, rich but not bad guys, and guys who have similar age to my dad"? Is that right?

I'm not sure about the じゃなければ part. Is it related to [も〜ば〜も construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/75242/41067)? I can't tell if whether the whole「お金持ってて悪い人じゃなければ」part is modifying「お父さんぐらいの歳のおじさん」or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> あのね
> Um... hey...
>
> リナ、パパ活やってるの
> I've actually been dong パパ活
>
> ...普通の食事だけじゃないやつ...
> It's the kind where you don't just go out with them for meals
>
> お金持ってて悪い人じゃなければ
> As long as they are rich and they are not bad people,
>
> お父さんぐらいの歳のおじさんとも
> with men around the same age as my dad
>
> 平気で寝られる
> I can also sleep without a problem

There, I put the lines into English in a rough translation based on my understanding.

- やつ in 普通の食事だけじゃないやつ doesn't refer to "guys". Here it means "the thing". Another way to say it is 普通の食事だけじゃないほう (you know, *that* kind)
- お金持ってて悪い人じゃなければ: お金持って(い)て悪い人じゃなければ As long as they are rich *and* not bad people
- お金持ってて悪い人じゃなければ talks about those お父さんぐらいの歳のおじさん, but doesn't modify that noun phrase. It is a conditional clause.

Comment: お金持ってて is simply *is rich **and***. So *as long as* for the both *rich* and *not bad*.

Comment: @sundowner Oh I see. I read too much into it then. Thanks!